# Attempting to access Expect object inside of Net::SSH::Expect gives an ERROR

Tags: perl, expect.pm

Perl: attempting to access Expect object inside of Net::SSH::Expect gives an ERROR.

Example pseudo code:

```
my $m = Net::SSH::Expect->new(
        host        => 192.168.1.6,
        user        => 'root',
        password    => 'password',
        timeout     => 10,
        raw_pty     => 1,
        log_file    => '/tmp/net_ssh_expect_output.txt',
    );

$m->login();

$m->expect->log_file();
```

This throws the error: expect():

> ERROR: if called directly (not as $obj->expect(...), but as Expect::expect(...), first parameter MUST be '-i' to set an object (list) for the patterns to work on. at (eval 99)[/usr/share/perl/5.18/perl5db.pl:732] line 2.

How should I be making the call to log_file() to grab the file handle and avoid that error message?

Here is the source code which is throwing the error: [Expect.pm line 492](https://metacpan.org/dist/Expect/source/lib/Expect.pm#L492).

I expect (heh heh) to get the file handle of the log file.  It looks like I am calling it as `$obj->expect()`, but it throws that error.  I'm probably missing something basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How should I be making the call to log_file() to grab the file handle and avoid that error message?

There is a specific method [`get_expect()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Expect#METHODS) that can be used to get the internal `Expect` object, you can use it like this:

```
my $logfile_handle = $m->get_expect()->log_file();
say {$logfile_handle} "Testing...";
```